# Программа которая в случае если один процесс был открыт больше другого процесса открывает картинку. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я хочу написать программу для своего сына, если процесс dota2.exe будет открыт дольше чем процесс devenv.exe то у него появиться картинка. Подскажите как это реализовать, код на Python

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Посмотрите на psutil (системные и технологические утилиты Python) — это кроссплатформенная библиотека для получения информации о запущенных процессах и использовании системы (ЦП, памяти, дисков, сети, датчиков) в Python. https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#processes